# C++ | pushing string into empty vector causes first element to be corrupted?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring, istringstream

I've been working on a `*.csv` parser and it works for the most part. Basically the parse works like this:

1. Open a stream for the designated `*.csv` file (filepath, number of data columns, and a delimiter must be supplied at constructor).
2. Get each line until the end of file. For each raw csv line extracted:

   i) Stream that line into a line_stream (using `std::istringstream`).

   ii) Break that stream into smaller string tokens (using the delimiter supplied at constructor) and push into a vector of strings.
3. Extracted data strings can be accessed through a private interface `database` interface until destruction of the parser object (or until I implement the string processor to convert them into workable data).

The parser object works, except that the very first character of the first string element of the vector always gets dropped. For example:

```
0544,1,Kitchenware,2,27
```

gets turned into:

```
544,1,Kitchenware,2,27
```

This is an unacceptable loss of information but I can't figure out the reason for this problem. I have worked around by pushing a `dummy` string before each packet iterator,

```
,ummy,0544,Kitchenware,27
```

but I still feel that this a very poor implementation.

---

I suspect it's a problem with the line_stream but not entirely sure how.

Below is the source code:

```
#ifndef _CSVPARSER_HPP
#define _CSVPARSER_HPP

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const char DEFAULT_COLUMNS_SEPARATOR = ',';

class csvStream {
 private:
  void _setOpen() { inStream.open(fpath, ios::in); }

 protected:
  string fpath;
  fstream inStream;

 public:
  explicit csvStream(const string& path) {
    fpath = path;
    _setOpen();
  }
};

template <typename T>
class csvParser : protected csvStream {
 private:
  int numDataTypes;
  char col_separator;
  string extractedRawLine;
  // Database of extracted packets of data as strings.
  vector<vector<string>*> database;

  // Return a reference to <data as a packet of strings>.
  vector<string>& _rawToStringPacket() {
    // line stream buffer & token
    istringstream line_stream;
    static string token;
    // new packet on the heap
    vector<string>* packet = nullptr;
    packet = new vector<string>;
    // extract strings into packet
    line_stream.str(extractedRawLine);

    packet->push_back("dummy");
    for (int i = 1; i < numDataTypes + 1; ++i) {
      getline(line_stream, token, col_separator);
      packet->push_back(token);
    }
    return *packet;
  }

  /****************************PUBLIC-API****************************/
 public:
  // Explicit Constructor: Must supply path to a *.csv file and the number of
  // data columns.
  explicit csvParser(const string& path,
                     const int ntypes,
                     const char sptr = ',')
      : csvStream(path), numDataTypes{ntypes}, col_separator{sptr} {}

  // Extract all data while stream is open.
  void extractAllRaw() {
    // continue to extract data until the end of file:
    while (getline(*inStream, extractedRawLine)) {
      static vector<string>* temp = nullptr;
      temp = &_rawToStringPacket();
      database.push_back(temp);
    }
  }

  // Stream the data elements to standard output.
  void printDatabase(ostream& os = cout) {
    for (auto i : database) {
      for (int j = 0; j < static_cast<int>(i->size()); ++j) {
        os << (*i)[j] << ",";
      }
      os << '\n';
    }
  }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. I find it hard to believe all that code is required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This code has an overuse of pointers and dynamically allocated memory.  If you reduced these two things, maybe the problem will solve itself.  Code like this: `string* fpath;` -- why is this a pointer to a `string` instead of just `string`?

Comment: You are right. I was overthinking about memory management.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and added a main() and it works for me: https://onlinegdb.com/H1J865hOP

Comment: Thanks @JerryJeremiah. Interesting result. I think I figured out the problem, it's probably because of the `\r` return character as the line gets streamed in. For some reason my compiler doesn't handle that return character.

Comment: Programs compiled with a Windows compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio) handle that because they expect the files to be Windows-like.  Programs compiled with a Unix compiler (GCC including MingW) probably expect the files to be Unix-like.  The carraige return would definitely explain it.